# How to copy files from windows to linux (cross platform)?

Tags: linux, shell, deployment, window, file-transfer

I want to trigger command/script from Linux environment which copies file from windows system to my Linux environment.

I have set up local Linux server for my web application. I am using WinSCP for file transfer and Putty as a console.

I want to automate the process of build deployment of Linux server.For that i have to copy build which is on my windows machine and paste it in my local Linux server so that i can deploy it.

As per my understanding, there should be some shared location which is accessible from Linux environment.

Is there is any script available for this? Also, please tell me the configuration changes require to do this.

Answer (score 3):

Install cygwin and you can use scp, ssh etc just like you would on linux. Besides, you can use ordinary bash scripts instead of crappy bat-files.

OR

http://www.codingepiphany.com/2014/01/13/batch-script-for-transferring-files-from-windows-machines-to-linux-file-server/

OR

Use samba

Answer (score 3):

You can use synchronize command of winscp from your windows,
[winscp synchronize command](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_synchronize)

or winscp.exe command from your command prompt.
[winscp.exe command](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/commandline)

Answer (score 0):

you can use rsync for synchronize your files. http://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync

Comment: I tried this , below is the response:

Unexpected local arg: AsopaDesktopTest-DTest_123.sh

If arg is a remote file/dir, prefix it with a colon (:).

rsync error: syntax or usage error (code 1) at main.c(1246) [Receiver=3.0.9]